# Using "from __future__ import division" in my program, but it isn't loaded with my program

Tags: python, sympy

I wrote the following program in Python 2 to do Newton's method computations for my math problem set, and while it works perfectly, for reasons unbeknownst to me, when I initially load it in ipython with `%run -i NewtonsMethodMultivariate.py`, the Python 3 division is not imported. I know this because after I load my Python program, entering `x**(3/4)` gives "1". After manually importing the new division, then `x**(3/4)` remains `x**(3/4)`, as expected. Why is this?

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import division
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, zeros

x, y = symbols('x y')
X = Matrix([[x],[y]])
tol = 1e-3

def roots(h,a):
  def F(s):
    return h.subs({x: s[0,0], y: s[1,0]})
  def D(s):
    return h.jacobian(X).subs({x: s[0,0], y: s[1,0]})
  if F(a) == zeros((2,1)):
    return a
  else:
    while (F(a)).norm() > tol:
      a = a - ((D(a))**(-1))*F(a)
      print a.evalf(10)
```

I would use Python 3 to avoid this issue, but my Linux distribution only ships SymPy for Python 2. Thanks to the help anyone can provide.

Also, in case anyone was wondering, I haven't yet generalized this script for nxn Jacobians,  and only had to deal with 2x2 in my problem set. <s>Additionally, I'm slicing the 2x2 zero matrix instead of using the command `zeros(2,1)` because SymPy 0.7.1, installed on my machine, complains that "zeros() takes exactly one argument", though the [wiki](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices.html) suggests otherwise. Maybe this command is only for the git version.</s> (Thanks eryksun for correcting my notation, which fixed the issue with the zeros function.)

Comment: It's `zeros((2,1))`; the argument is either a scalar or a tuple. Did you test division immediately after the import with `print 1/2`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you add `print division` to the end of your program? Does it print something like: `_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)`? And if so, what does that same print statement give you from the ipython command line? Note that there are several tens of thousands of Google results for "ipython from future import division". It seems you're not the first to notice this. :-)

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for correcting me on my usage of the zeros command; I've updated my program. So if I open ipython, run `from __future__ import division`, and then `print 1/2`, the result is 0.5, as expected. But if I instead, upon opening ipython and running `%run -i NewtonsMethodMultivariate.py`, and then `print 1/2`, I get 0. The line to import the Python 3 division is clearly in my program, so I don't know what's up.

Comment: @KirkStrauser I have googled this, but the fix is to use the import line for division that I cited above, but why doesn't it seem to have an effect? From the iPython command line, I get exactly what you said after adding `print division` to the last line of my program. From the commandline I also get the same.

Comment: Why would you hardcode your `h` function or consider moving to py3 instead of entering `x**(3/4.)` or `x**0.75` ?

Comment: @JohnMachin I simply wanted to avoid decimals. Also, my matrix `a` had fractions in it (which hardcoding `h` would not fix), and in the first iteration, with fractions in the entries of `a` gave a better solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `ipython -i` command and `run -i` in `ipython` interpreter ignore `from __future__ import division` in `print05.py` script.

```
$ cat print05.py 
from __future__ import division
print(1/2)
```

In `ipython` console:

```
In [1]: print 1/2
0
In [2]: run -i print05.py
0.5
In [3]: division
Out[3]: _Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
In [4]: print 1/2
0
In [5]: from __future__ import division
In [6]: print 1/2
0.5
```

`execfile` and `import` produce the same result:

```
>>> print 1/2
0
>>> execfile('print05.py')
0.5
>>> print 1/2
0
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> print 1/2
0.5
```

`from __future__ import division` should not have effect on the source code from different modules, otherwise it would break code in other modules that don't expect its presence.

Here, `from __future__ import division` has effect:

```
$ python -i print05.py
0.5
>>> print 1/2
0.5
>>> division
_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
```

The module name in this case is `__main__` both inside `print05.py` and in the prompt.

Here, the first `print 1/2` executes in `print05` module, the second one in `__main__` module so it also works as expected:

```
$ python -im print05
0.5
>>> print 1/2
0
```

And here's something wrong:

```
$ ipython -i print05.py
0.5
In [1]: division
Out[1]: _Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
In [2]: print 1/2
0
```

The docs for [`__future__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#future)  say:

> If an interpreter is started with the -i option, is passed a script
>   name to execute, and the script includes a future statement, it will
>   be in effect in the interactive session started after the script is
>   executed.

So It might be a bug in `ipython` if its `-i` option tries to emulate the same python option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It's unfortunate, because I inputed my function "h" on the ipython commandline, and it has terms with fractional exponents, but I guess I have to hardcode "h" into the program if I don't want to import future division manually.

Comment: @Sara Fauzia: if you defined `h()` function *before* `..import division` then it will use *integer* division. You could use `edit you_module.py` to add functions from `ipython` console.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian So using python interactively, as you pointed out, indeeds does work properly, as I just tested. Is this a bug, what happens with ipython?

Comment: @Sara Fauzia: There's a [sympy profile](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/config/profile/sympy/ipython_config.py) that imports future division.

Comment: @eryksun But the default profile imports everything, and I thought this is eschewed from in an individual program. (Correct me if I'm mistaken, as I am a newbie.)

Comment: @Sara Fauzia: I've updated the answer with a quote from `__future__`'s documentation.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian From iPython's 0.11 [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#interactive-use): "IPython is meant to work as a drop-in replacement for the standard interactive interpreter. As such, any code which is valid python should execute normally under IPython (cases where this is not true should be reported as bugs)." So, unless I've misunderstood, I should file a bug report.

Comment: @Sara Fauzia: Even if the behavior is expected for `ipython` then at least `ipython` documentation for `-i` option should mention that it doesn't confirm to `python -i` expectations, so it is worth to file a bug report. btw, `jython` (Python implemented in Java) works as expected and it print `0.5`. But `ipython` is not along `pypy` (Python implemented in RPython) also prints `0`.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy also provides a script -- isympy -- which is a wrapper for IPython which executes some common commands, including an import of division from future. It's quite handy, and in newer IPython versions (0.11+) it also allows automatic constructions of Symbols (which is nice as I always seem to forget); run it with the -a parameter.

As for Python 3, there is support for it in the development version and the next release will have it; when distributions are going to pack it I don't know.